# Странная работа StartsWith

Tags: c#, linq

Получаю тест из Excel файла.

```
protected override string TakeTextFromFile(string Path)
    {
        var workbook = new Workbook();
        workbook.LoadFromFile(Path);
        var sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        var temporaryFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".txt";
        sheet.SaveToFile(temporaryFileName, " ", Encoding.UTF8);

        var textFromFile = File.ReadAllText(temporaryFileName).Replace(@"\", "").Replace("\"", "").Split(new string[1] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var result = "";
        foreach (var text in textFromFile)
            result += text;
        return result;
    }
```

Результат метода TakeTextFromFile передаю в метод SearchTextInText. SearchTextInText("qweqweqweqweqwадресячсчсясячсячс", "адрес"). Цель метода: найти количество вхождения строки в текст.

```
/// <summary>
    /// Поиск текста в другом тексте
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="TextForSearch">Текст, в котором будет происходить поиск</param>
    /// <param name="SearchText">Текст, который нужно найти в тексте</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static int SearchTextInText(string TextForSearch, string SearchText)
    {
        int findedCount = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < TextForSearch.Count(); i++)
        {
            var text = TextForSearch.Remove(0, i + 1);
            if (text.StartsWith(SearchText))
                findedCount++;
        }
        return findedCount;
    }
```

Вывод метода SearchTextInText = 0, что есть неправильно.

Если конкретнее, то, когда переменная text в методе SearchTextInText становится равным адресячсчсясячсячс, условие в методе возвращает false.

До этого использовал Split и считал по количеству элементов в массиве. Результат тот же.

**В чём проблема? Как можно переделать метод SearchTextInText?**

Comment: у вас проблема с `public static int SearchTextInText(string TextForSearch, string SearchText)` ? Приведите конкретные строки, с которыми вы его вызываете, ожидаемый от него результат и результат, что вы получаете.

Comment: так вы сами \ удалили, а после этого хотите чтобы сплит по NewLine отработал. Во втором случае вы не правильно понимаете суть StartWith - этот метод возвращает истину тогда и только тогда, когда начальные символы строки совпадают с заданной строкой, а у вас приведен пример, в котором искомое находится в середине, и результат, ожидаемо, false

Comment: @rdorn, первый пример кода просто получает текст из Excel файла. Результат этого метода передаётся в метод SearchTextInText. Если вы посмотрите **внимательнее** то с каждым проходом цикла он удаляет начальные символы и с каждым разом больше на один. Таким образом с несколькими проходами цикла переменная text станет равным адресячсчсясячсячс. Тем самым условие должно вренуть true.

Comment: Ок, пусть так. Проверил исполнение вашего поискового метода, на заданной строке работает, условно правильно. Условно, потому что в строке "aaa" находит подстроку "aa" всего один раз, чтобы исправить, нужно убрать +1 при удалении первого символа. Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что проблема в получении исходного текста. Это уже проверить за вас не смогу, используйте отладчик и точки останова.

Answer (score 0):

> В чём проблема? Как можно переделать метод SearchTextInText?

Хоть ваша ошибка, скорее всего, не связана, с методом SearchTextInText, т.к. код метода я проверил на исполнение и его поведение не отличается от ожидаемого, но кое что исправить в нем все равно необходимо.

1. В цикле

   ```
   for(var i = 0; i < TextForSearch.Count(); i++)
   {
       var text = TextForSearch.Remove(0, i + 1);
       if (text.StartsWith(SearchText))
           findedCount++;
   }
   ```

   вы сразу удаляете первый символ и только потом проверяете начало строки, это приведет к тому, что если исходная строка начинается с искомой, это не будет обнаружено, т.к. первый символ вы уже отрезали. Исправить просто:

   ```
   for(var i = 0; i < TextForSearch.Count(); i++)
   {
       //var text = TextForSearch.Remove(0, i + 1);
       var text = TextForSearch.Remove(0, i);
       if (text.StartsWith(SearchText))
           findedCount++;
   }
   ```
2. Вторая проблема в том, что ваш метод поиска генерирует массу мусорных объектов при удалении начальных символов, что создает ненужную дополнительную нагрузку по сборке мусора. И если в учебной программе это будет незаметно, т.к. она,скорее всего, закончит работу до первого обращения к GC, то в продуктовом варианте такое поведение неприемлемо.

   ```
   public static int SearchTextInText(string TextForSearch, string SearchText)
   {
       int startidx = 0;
       int findIdx;
       int count = 0;
       while ((findIdx = TextForSearch.IndexOf(SearchText, startidx)) >= 0)
       {
           startidx = findIdx + 1;
           count++;
       }
       return count;
   }
   ```

   В таком варианте новые строки не генерируются, а сам поиск выполняется в нативном коде (реализацию IndexOf смотри в ILSpy или на [refferencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/))